# dictionary extraction to pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

Based on this dictionary:

```
dictionary = {
    "base_name" : ["abc", "abc_2"],
    "conditional" : {
        "base_name" : "abc_cond",
        "conditions" : [{"func" : "==", "ref" : 1}],
        "res" : -0.044
    },
    "outlier" : 0.232,
    "out_name" : "var",
    "transformation" : [
        {"func" : "==", "ref" : -1, "res" : -0.323},
        {"func" : "<=", "ref" : 23, "res" : -0.123},
        {"func" : ">", "ref" : -5, "res" : -0.433},
        {"func" : "else", "res" : -0.663},
    ]
}
```

What's the best way to extract these values to pandas dataframe?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. SO is a Q&A site, but this isn't a question, and it's not clear what you need help with. Also, that code isn't even close to complete; maybe you posted the wrong code? For tips, see [ask].

Comment: I posted the desired output what I'm looking for, I couldn't figure out how to get the "func", "ref" and "res" columns. Can you help me understand what else is needed so I can improve the question?

Comment: Thanks for posting more complete code. Now, what about the rest of it? Like, when you tried to write code to create the first two rows, where did you get stuck? This site isn't for "guiding" per se; please read the links I posted to learn how to use this site.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do. I'm not 100% sure about "outlier". Is it always called that? Or do you need to figure out what the other key is, which in this case is outlier?

Is there a list of dictionaries to process, or just this one?

```py
import pandas as pd

dictionary = {
    "base_name" : ["abc", "abc_2"],
    "conditional" : {
        "base_name" : "abc_cond",
        "conditions" : [{"func" : "==", "ref" : 1}],
        "res" : -0.044
    },
    "outlier" : 0.232,
    "out_name" : "var",
    "transformation" : [
        {"func" : "==", "ref" : -1, "res" : -0.323},
        {"func" : "<=", "ref" : 23, "res" : -0.123},
        {"func" : ">", "ref" : -5, "res" : -0.433},
        {"func" : "else", "res" : -0.663},
    ]
}

data = []

# Root level
row = {
    "name": dictionary["out_name"],
    "org_name": dictionary["base_name"],
    "func": "outlier",
    "ref": "",
    "res": dictionary["outlier"]
}

data.append(row)

# Conditional
row = {
    "name": dictionary["out_name"],
    "org_name": dictionary["conditional"]["base_name"],
    "func": dictionary["conditional"]["conditions"][0]["func"],
    "ref": dictionary["conditional"]["conditions"][0]["ref"],
    "res": dictionary["conditional"]["res"]
}

data.append(row)

# Each transformation
for transformation in dictionary["transformation"]:
    row = {
        "name": dictionary["out_name"],
        "org_name": dictionary["base_name"],
        "func": transformation["func"],
        "ref": transformation.get("ref", ""),
        "res": transformation["res"]
    }
    
    data.append(row)

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  name      org_name     func ref    res
0  var  [abc, abc_2]  outlier      0.232
1  var      abc_cond       ==   1 -0.044
2  var  [abc, abc_2]       ==  -1 -0.323
3  var  [abc, abc_2]       <=  23 -0.123
4  var  [abc, abc_2]        >  -5 -0.433
5  var  [abc, abc_2]     else     -0.663
```

---

Your attempt only gets the transformations part of the dictionary. You need to explicitly get the other parts of the dictionary, too.

Also, before unpacking the transformation dictionary, first set the `ref` value to an empty string, otherwise all the `int`s will be implicitly transformed to `float`s.

```
import pandas as pd

dictionary = {
    "base_name" : ["abc", "abc_2"],
    "conditional" : {
        "base_name" : "abc_cond",
        "conditions" : [{"func" : "==", "ref" : 1}],
        "res" : -0.044
    },
    "outlier" : 0.232,
    "out_name" : "var",
    "transformation" : [
        {"func" : "==", "ref" : -1, "res" : -0.323},
        {"func" : "<=", "ref" : 23, "res" : -0.123},
        {"func" : ">", "ref" : -5, "res" : -0.433},
        {"func" : "else", "res" : -0.663},
    ]
}

data = []

# Root level
data.append({
    "name": dictionary["out_name"],
    "org_name": dictionary["base_name"],
    "func": "outlier",
    "ref": "",
    "res": dictionary["outlier"]
})

# Conditional
data.append({
    "name": dictionary["out_name"],
    "org_name": dictionary["conditional"]["base_name"],
    "func": dictionary["conditional"]["conditions"][0]["func"],
    "ref": dictionary["conditional"]["conditions"][0]["ref"],
    "res": dictionary["conditional"]["res"]
})

# Transformations
for transformation in dictionary["transformation"]:
    data.append({
        "name" : dictionary["out_name"],
        "org_name" : dictionary["base_name"],
        "ref": "", # If ref is missing in one of the dicts, pandas implicitly 
                   # transforms all the ints to floats.
        **transformation,
})

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  name      org_name     func ref    res
0  var  [abc, abc_2]  outlier      0.232
1  var      abc_cond       ==   1 -0.044
2  var  [abc, abc_2]       ==  -1 -0.323
3  var  [abc, abc_2]       <=  23 -0.123
4  var  [abc, abc_2]        >  -5 -0.433
5  var  [abc, abc_2]     else     -0.663
```

Comment: It is always called "outlier". I edited the question with what I've been working on, it involves dictionary unpacking and I think I'm pretty close just need some tweaking, do you think you can help with improving what I have?

Comment: No problemo. I've updated my answer. Have a squiz. It should be pretty self explanatory. Let me know if you want me to explain anything in particular.